# How to extract name/URI of the input XML file in Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I want to include last modification date in the output document. I want it to be last modification date of the input XML file. For this purposes I could use the  construction below. Though, how could I extract the name of the input XML file to use it with Apache FOP in the construction instead of the manually specified `input.xml`?

<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy&#x2212;MM&#x2212;dd',java:java.util.Locale.new('EN')), java:java.util.Date.new(java:lastModified(java:java.io.File.new('input.xml'))))"/>

Comment: I don't think it's possible with XSLT 1.0 - but you could pass the file's path to the stylesheet as a parameter at runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to extract value of the `-xml` attribute passed to the FOP, so that not to define a separate parameter?

Comment: "*Is it possible to extract value of the -xml attribute passed to the FOP*" No.